# User Defined Input in one function returning no value in another function Python

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to fetch the Contact-Us URLs from multiple websites. The below code doesn't produce any error, but not generating any output. The Function find_link is producing the desired output, but function contact_check doesn't generate any output.

```
import xlrd
import os
import re
import requests
import pandas
import sys
from sys import exit
from operator import contains
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Comment
import urllib.request


headers = {'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',}
def tag_visible(element):
    if element.parent.name in ['style', 'script', 'head', 'title', 'meta', '[document]']:
        return False
    if isinstance(element, Comment):
        return False
    return True

def find_link(url):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
    txt = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    links = []
    for link in txt.findAll('a'):
        links.append(link.get('href'))
    return r, links
def contact_check(links):
    url1 = ''
    match = ['contact','contact us','contact-us','Contact Us','Contact us', 'Contact', 'Contact US','contactus','ContactUS','ContactUs']
    for link in links:
        if (any(b in i for b in match) for i in link):
            url1 = link
    return url1

text = contact_check(find_link("https://www.genre.com/"))
print(text)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !!
Thanks !!

Comment: Irrespective of the case, string with Contact/Contact Us/Contact-Us is identified & appended to the original link, to get the contact us URL of this website, for example :- https://www.genre.com/contactus/?c=n for the website used in code.

Comment: So if my understanding is right then you are trying to search https://www.genre.com/ 
 ie a specific url from 107 urls?

Comment: Wouldn't it be wise if you only check if the `url` contains `contact`, `contactus` etc?

Comment: @bertdida :- Yes, that would also solve the purpose, but i am not sure how to achieve that. Could you please suggest a better way.

Comment: You wont believe how easy it is in python to check if string contains a substring. I think `contact_check` should return `list`?

Comment: I did try it that way, but it is returning the same set of list as links, and not only the list containing the word "Contact". I have edited the code for showing my attempt. Please help !!